# pvcreate failing to create PV. Device not found /dev/sdxy (or ignored by filtering)

Tags: linux, lvm

I have an oVirt installation with CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611.

I want to add a new drive (sdb) to the oVirt volume group to work with VMs.

Here is the result of fdisk on the drive:

```
[root@host1 ~]# fdisk /dev/sdb Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.23.2).

Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them. Be
careful before using the write command.

Orden (m para obtener ayuda): p

Disk /dev/sdb: 300.1 GB, 300069052416 bytes, 586072368 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes Sector size (logical/physical): 512
bytes / 512 bytes I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes Disk
label type: dos Identificador del disco: 0x7a33815f

Disposit. Inicio Comienzo Fin Bloques Id Sistema
/dev/sdb1 2048 586072367 293035160 8e Linux LVM
```

The partitions are showed up in /proc/partitions:

```
[root@host1 ~]# cat /proc/partitions
major minor #blocks name

8 0 293036184 sda
8 1 1024 sda1
8 2 1048576 sda2
8 3 53481472 sda3
8 4 1 sda4
8 5 23072768 sda5
8 6 215429120 sda6
8 16 293036184 sdb
8 17 293035160 sdb1
```

When I execute the command to create PV with "pvcreate /dev/sdb1" the result is:

```
[root@host1 ~]# pvcreate /dev/sdb1

Device /dev/sdb1 not found (or ignored by filtering).
```

I have revised the file /etc/lvm/lvm.conf for the filters, but I do not have any filter that makes LVM discarding the drive. I have rebooted the computer after creating the PV with pvcreate. I did research on Google for the error but no idea.

Thanks. Any help would be appreciated Manuel

Comment: This probably belongs on Unix and Linux SE or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit lvm.conf uncomment global_flter and edit like this

> global_filter = [ "a|/dev/sdb|"]

After that edit multipath vi /etc/multipath.conf

> [root@ovirtnode2 ~]#lsblk /dev/sdb NAME
>   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT sdb
>   8:16   0  200G  0 disk   └─3678da6e715b018f01f1abdb887594aae 253:2
>   0  200G  0 mpath

edit 
vi /etc/multipath.conf

> #### append the following to multipath.conf blacklist {
>
> ```
>     wwid 3678da6e715b018f01f1abdb887594aae }
> ```

service multipathd restart

its work for me, and i have that problem to when im trying on ovirt but

> [root@ovirtnode2 ~]# pvcreate /dev/sdb   Physical volume "/dev/sdb"
>   successfully created. [root@ovirtnode2 ~]#